# Is apache asyncClient actual async or it uses thread behind the scene

Tags: java, apache, http, asynchronous, apache-httpclient-4.x

I was looking for async java http client.

I came across [Apache asyncClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-4.0.x/index.html) and went through the following [examples](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/httpasyncclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/nio/client/AsyncClientHttpExchangeFutureCallback.java).

so in example we register a callback object and completed(...) get called when the response of the request come back.

QUESTION:

Now internally does the ASyncClient

[1](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-4.0.x/index.html) make thread to wait per request or

[2](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/httpasyncclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/nio/client/AsyncClientHttpExchangeFutureCallback.java) it actually use the  NIO and make one thread to poll the socket selectors and call the completed(...)  method

Comment: Apache is a great open-source organization, and it provides the source of this package, [fully available on the web with cross-referencing](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-4.0.x/httpasyncclient/xref/index.html). You can see exactly what they are doing by reading the source.

Comment: @RealSkeptic true but i am trying to take advantage of large community which apache has...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache HttpAsyncClient is based on Apache HttpCore NIO, which is a low level HTTP transport library based on Java NIO.